# Can mobile browsers access contact list on the device?

Tags: html, cross-browser, mobile-browser

Can mobile browsers access contact list on the device? For instance, iOS Safari could access iPhone contacts or similarly Chrome could access iOS Contacts or Chrome for Android, Firefox for Android and so on?

I was hoping to SMS some links with contacts but need this functionality to work agnostic of the mobile browser or device or OS.Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid the short answer is No you can't

Answer (score 0):

There were some suggestions from the WC3 to add an API "Contacts API", but it never really picked up, mainly for security reasons I believe.

You can read about the draft here: https://www.w3.org/TR/contacts-api/